# How do I store numbers in two arrays with specific order?

Tags: c++, file, text, storage

I want to open a text file and read it in its entirety while storing its contents into arrays using c++. I have my example text file below. I would like to store the first number into an array and the rest of them into a 2nd array line by line. For example 9 to be stored in first array and 22 22 at second array,then 1 to be stored at first array 2 3 4 at second array etc...I am not sure how to accomplish this in c++, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
               9 22 22
               1 2 3 4
               1 5
               2 3 6 9
```

For example when I print the first array i want to show: 9 1 1 2 (first column)
and when I print the second array I would like to show: 22 22 2 3 4 etc...

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. You show the input, but what is the output you want?

Comment: It is difficult to understand where is your problem. You may define two `std::vector` then read the file line per line (`getline`) etc. It would be easier for us to help you if you show an attempt

Comment: Also include your current code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: For the first array i want to be 9 1 1 2 (number in first column) for the second array 22 22 2 3 4... (the rest numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

- Create a loop goes on for as long as you can successfully read a line from the file. You'll need a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for that.
- In the loop:

  - Put the line you read in an [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to simplify the extraction.
  - Declare a temporary variable to use for extracting the numbers.
  - Try to extract a number from the `istringstream`.
  - If you successfully extracted a number:

    - Put the extracted number in `arr1`.
    - Create another loop where you extract all the rest of the numbers one by one from the `istringstream` and put them in `arr2`.